# get user document path on remote pc

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to determine if a user is using a .PST file with Outlook.

Starting with the basics (then I'll incorporate a foreach loop later).

```
$Computer = "Computer1"
$split = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $computer | select username
$User= $split -split 'DOMAIN\\'
$PST = Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\C$\users\$User\Documents\Outlook Files" -Include *.pst -Recurse -Force
```

My issue is getting the computer user's name extracted as the actual name as a string

\Computer1\C$\users\@{username=SomeUser}\Documents\Outlook Files

Is there a better way to get the current logged in users name from a given PC?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$user` assignment to:

`$User= $split.username -split 'DOMAIN\\'`

So:

```
$Computer = "Computer1"
$split = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $computer | select username
$User= $split.username -split 'DOMAIN\\'
$PST = Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\C$\users\$User\Documents\Outlook Files" -Include *.pst -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative solution.  Is there a "best practice" reason to use one over the other?

Comment: Not as far as I can see, it's really down to programmer preference.

Answer (score 0):

Add **expandproperty** to **select-object**

```
$Computer = "Computer1" 
$split = gwmi win32_computersystem -comp $computer | select -expand username
$User= $split -split 'DOMAIN\\'
.....
```

Comment: From experience: wmi does not always read this correctly. It sometimes (maybe 1/100) returns no user logged in for no apparent reason.

Comment: Just found an issue: $user results in someuser (as expected).  Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\C$\users\$User\Documents\Outlook Files"  Results in Get-ChildItem "\\$Computer\C$\users\ someuser\Documents\Outlook Files"  How would I get rid of the leading space?